# comparison between two times

Tags: php

I am developing a website on php. I am submitting a time field as M:SAM or PM (EX: 10:55AM) something like this. I want to compare this field with current time. I am getting the current time by using this code.

```
$time = date("h:i A");
$time = str_replace(' ','',$time);
```

But here I want to compare this current time with database result.

Thanks
Sateesh.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `10:55AM` you can convert it to timestamp:

```
$input     = '10:55PM';
$timestamp = strtotime($input);
$output    = date('H:i', $timestamp);

// output is 22:55 (because of PM in my example so it's correct)
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I compare this current time with the database value like some duetime < $output

Comment: @sateesh Run the strtotime on the database value, should work.

Comment: I do not know where is the problem - don't you know how to make mysql query or what ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $time1);
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $time2);
if ($a < $b) {
  // $a before $b
}
```

This one expects both dates as `12:34AM`. You can change the format (separately) like you want. Have a look at [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)